# Adding two calculated times together in PHP

Tags: php, time

I need some help, I have already previously calculated my times for a weekly timesheet in PHP, not my question; is it possible to add these all together?

I tried to use the following function but i'm not sure this works. The aim is for each week to calculate how much time is spent in total in this format.

```
$time = "18 hours 13 minutes";
$time2 = "47 minutes";
$time3 = "1 hour";
$time4 = "1 hour";
$time5 = "1 hour";
$time6 = "";
$time7 = "";

$max_date=abs(strtotime($time) + strtotime($time2) + strtotime($time3) + strtotime($time4) + strtotime($time5) + strtotime($time6) + strtotime($time7));
```

So in all it should show 22 hours as the total.

Thats if this is possible?

Comment: You should store the time in minutes, not as formatted strings and format them on output instead. Then you just need to sum them all up straight away. Right now, you would need to parse the strings "18 hours 13 minutes" as minutes before you sum them all up. The function `strtotime()` takes a date/time string as an argument and turns it into a unix timestamp (how many seconds since 1970-01-01) which is not really what you're looking for here.

Comment: Btw, if you sum up the times in your example, it would be 22 hours, not 20.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects. We create two identical objects using the current time, then we use the [`modify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method to add each of the time variables to one of them. We can then take the difference between the two objects (creating a [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object) and output the value of that in the same [format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) as the inputs:

```
$start = new DateTime();
$end = clone($start);

if (!empty($time)) $end->modify("+$time");
if (!empty($time2)) $end->modify("+$time2");
if (!empty($time3)) $end->modify("+$time3");
if (!empty($time4)) $end->modify("+$time4");
if (!empty($time5)) $end->modify("+$time5");
if (!empty($time6)) $end->modify("+$time6");
if (!empty($time7)) $end->modify("+$time7");

$total = $end->diff($start);
echo $total->format('%h hours %i minutes');
```

Output:

```
22 hours 0 minutes
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/FI63K)